# Attribute value of XML node in Scala

Tags: xml, scala

Suppose I am writing a function `(Node, String) => Option[String]` to get attribute value by attribute name from a given node.

```
def getAttributeValue(node: Node, attributeName: String): Option[String] = {
  val txt = (node \ ("@" + attributeName)).text
  if (txt.isEmpty) None else Some(txt)
}
```

Does it make sense ? How would you fix/improve it ?

Comment: Makes sense to me. One idea could be to provide an implicit class adding the attribute getter onto Node to get a more concise way to call the method. Something like: node.attribute(name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala has methods [`attribute`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/scala-xml/index.html#scala.xml.Node@attribute%28uri:String,key:String%29:Option[Seq[scala.xml.Node]]) defined on `Node` class, but they return `Option[Seq[Node]]`, which requires further processing to get a `String`.

So I'm currently using something very similar in my code:

```
implicit class XmlEnhancements(node: Node) {
  def attributeOpt(attribute: String): Option[String] =
    node.attribute(attribute) flatMap (_.headOption) map (_.text)
}
```

Also, as Scala itself defines method [`def \@(attributeName: String): String`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/scala-xml/index.html#scala.xml.Node@%5C@%28attributeName:String%29:String) on the `xml.Node` class, I believe it's also OK to define this `attributeOpt` under `\@?` alias:

```
implicit class XmlEnhancements(node: Node) {
  def \@?(attribute: String): Option[String] =
    node \@ attribute match {
      case "" => None
      case s => Some(s)
    }
}
```